# Previously created view(Button) is overlapping the newly generated View(RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, z-index

I have programatically created the following layout using absolute positioning:-

[image]

When user enters 3 or more characters in the EditView (TextEdit: 107), a Selection List(RecyclerView) will appear below the Editview.
But the button is overlapping the RecyclerView as shown:-

[image]

Now, According the my understanding if the position of views overlaps then they appears in in the order they have been generated i.e. added to the parent view. So acc. to that RecyclerView that's added to the RelativeLayout at last should have overlapped the button and the button should be hidden below it. but that's not happening, could someone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Is it actually added or is it simply made visible?

Comment: Can you provide the code of your layout?

Comment: @Ivo It's actually added

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev sorry, due to some constraits, can't provide the code

Comment: @Jatinguglani, Without XML code and knowing layout properties it's hard to tell what's the solution.